# Android Eclipse not able to see older emulator in Android device chooser

Tags: android, android-emulator

In My project I used android:minSdkVersion="7".When I run my project it don't show api7 emulator(Already created in AVD with api7) in **Android Device Chooser**.Problem occured After updating eclipse ADT with revision 22.6.3.

Comment: Problem occured after updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart ADB (you can do this in the 'DDMS Perspective', or from the command-line).

Command line to restart:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

If the device is configured correctly (USB Debugging enabled, and the computers drivers installed) - it should show up.

There are no issues I have encountered with the new tools where devices don't show (ie. I think there is something with your device, or configuration, not the tools themselves)

Comment: Already did this step and also restart my PC but no result and I want to test project on emulator not on device